# git fetch を実行してもローカルに反映されません

Tags: git

初心者です。練習しています。

GitHubのコードを編集し `git fetch origin/main` と実行しました。コミット名はUpdate2です。

[image: github]

そのうえでローカルのターミナルより `git fetch`  コマンドを実行しました。

```
github_practice ±|main|→ git fetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 669 bytes | 39.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/blueletter/github_practice
   7569c99..053f5b8  main       -> origin/main
```

そして、`git log --oneline` で状態を確認しました。すると以下のように出力され、リモートでの変更が反映されていません。

```
7569c99 (HEAD -> main) Update README.md
07ffa19 Initial commit
(END)
```

VSCodeでフォルダを見てみると以下のような画面になっています。
円状のアイコンにマウスオーバーすると "origin/mainから1件のコミットをプルします" と出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

自分が参考にしている教材では `git fetch` だけでうまく行くようですが、やってみるとうまくいきません。

この原因のわかるからいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git fetch` を実行した場合には、リモートリポジトリから履歴情報の取得のみを行います。
リモートリポジトリの変更をローカルにも反映するには、`git fetch` 後に `git merge` を実行するか、fetch の代わりに `git pull` を実行してください。

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/main
```

または

```
$ git pull
```

Comment: よく理解できました。どうもありがとうございます。